# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘roxygen2’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):

Tags: r, roxygen

roxygen2 seems to hate me.  I installed it within R 3.6.3 OS X 10.14.6 and it seemed to go fine:

```
> install.packages("roxygen2")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/cran/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/roxygen2_7.1.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 955820 bytes (933 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 933 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/lm/c2f0w7g95q18plrh3bzc8klmfjh9r3/T//RtmphL5OZw/downloaded_packages
```

But then....

```
> library(roxygen2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘roxygen2’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.14)
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
```

How do I repair this?

Comment: I'd try re-installing Rcpp, or updating all of your packages.

Comment: Reinstalling Rcpp seemed to do the trick, thanks!